# Grouping together same XML attributes in Python 3.6

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am generating a XML file using data from DB.
The data I am getting is similar to this:

ID- 1,2,1,3

Name- A,B,C,D

Age-  20,25,20,20

Currently using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
Root=ET.Element("root")
Resultlist= <<fetching from a Database
for row in Resultlist:
  Id=ET.SubElement(Root,"ID")
  Id.set("id",str(row[1]))
  Details=ET.SubElement(Id,"Details")
  Details.set("Name",str(row[2]))
  Details.set("Age",str(row[3])
```

The output I get is

```
<root>
   <ID id="1">
     <Details Age="20" Name="A" />
   </ID>
   <ID id="2">
     <Details Age="25" Name="B" />
   </ID>
   <ID id="1">
      <Details Age="20" Name="C" />
   </ID>
   <ID id="3">
     <Details Age="20" Name="D" />
   </ID>
</root>
```

How do I modify this to get output such that all the ones with same ID are in grouped together?

```
<root>
 <ID id="1">
  <Details Age="20" Name="A" />
  <Details Age="20" Name="C" />
 </ID>
 <ID id="2">
  <Details Age="25" Name="B" />
  </ID>
 <ID id="3">
  <Details Age="20" Name="D" />
 </ID>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a dictionary from your *ResultSet* with keys being the ID. Then add a nested loop for other values per each distinct ID:

```
Resultlist = [(1, 1, 20, "A"), (2, 2, 25, "B"), (3, 1, 20, "C"), (4, 3, 20, "D")]

# INITIALIZE DICTIONARY OF EMBEDDED LISTS
my_dict = {row[1]:[] for row in Resultlist} 

# APPEND NESTED LISTS TO DICTIONARY
for row in Resultlist:
    my_dict[row[1]].append([row[2], row[3]])

Root = ET.Element("root")

# ITERATE THROUGH DICTIONARY
for k, v in my_dict.items():

    Id = ET.SubElement(Root, "ID")
    Id.set("id", str(k))

    for i in v:
        Details = ET.SubElement(Id, "Details")
        Details.set("Name", str(i[0]))
        Details.set("Age", str(i[1]))
```